# Espresso : IllegalStateException: No lifecycle monitor registered

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am not able to execute test cases using espresso-2.2.2 it throws below exception. I did research to solve error but do not found the solution. Please help me to fix the issue.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No lifecycle monitor registered! Are you running under an Instrumentation which registers lifecycle monitors?
>   at android.support.test.runner.lifecycle.ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance(ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.java:44)
>   at android.support.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule.provideLifecycleMonitor(BaseLayerModule.java:52)
>   at android.support.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideLifecycleMonitorFactory.get(BaseLayerModule_ProvideLifecycleMonitorFactory.java:18)

Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':domain')
    compile project(':data')

    compile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1"
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2"
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1"
    compile "io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14"
    compile "com.android.support:design:23.4.0"
    compile "io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1"
    provided "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:0.5"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:0.5"
}
```

Custom test runner defined in app level gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.myapp.presentation.TestRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Custom test runner is here
    package com.myapp.presentation;

```
public class TestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments)
    {
        MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
        super.onCreate(arguments);
    }
}
```

Here is my test class

```
import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class ProductDetailsActivityTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<ProductDetailsActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(ProductDetailsActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void listGoesOverTheFold() {
        onView(withId(R.id.view_pager)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution while checking the [commit on the Android clean architecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/pull/84/files).

Problem was due to dependency

> androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1"

I have removed this dependency and now I am able to execute the test cases with Espresso-v2.2.2